# AJAX Authentication Failed

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to call a WebMethod using AJAX in ASP.net

When debugging, I encountered the following error

```
{Message: "Authentication failed.", StackTrace: null,…}
ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"
Message: "Authentication failed."
StackTrace: null
```

AJAX:

```
                                <script type="text/javascript">  

                                    function SaveRecord() {
                                        //Get control's values  

                                        var year = $("#yeartxt").val();
                                        var title = $("#titletxt").val();
                                        var content = $("#contenttxt").val();

                                        //Jquery Ajax call to server side method  
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "Page.aspx/InsertDetails",
                                            data: "{'Year':" + year + ",'Title':" + title + ",'Content':" + content + "}",
                                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                            dataType: "json",
                                            success: function (data) {
                                                alert("Updated!");
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }
                                </script>
```

WebMethod:

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static string InsertDetails(string Year, string Title, string Content)
```

RouteConfig:

```
            var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
            settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
```

WebConfig:

```
     <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="./SignIn.aspx"></forms>
      </authentication>
```

I implemented the form authentication using ASP.net Identity.

Any ways to solve this?

Comment: With only the error it's hard to help you, it would be better if you included the ajax code. Maybe also the endpoint

Comment: Updated. I added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
 $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "Page.aspx/InsertDetails",
                                        data: JSON.stringify({ 'Year': Year, 'Title': Title, 'Content': content  }),
                                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        success: function (data) {
                                            alert("Updated!");
                                        }
                                    });
```

RouteConfig:

Comment this code

```
//settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

Comment: it gave this error {Message: "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'Year'.",…}
ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"
Message: "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'Year'."

Comment: pass a hardcoded parameters.

EX : data: JSON.stringify({ 'Year': 1992, 'Title': 'xyz', 'Content': 'Your Content'  })

Comment: It worked this way `data: '{Year: "' + year + '", Title: "' + title + '", Content: "' + content + '" }',` Appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably your data object which is not well defined.

```
const data = {'Year':year,'Title': title, 'Content': content};
```

abd then in your request:

```
...
data: JSON.stringify(data),
...
```

THis should work, as you have mentioned the data type to be *json*

Comment: I tried defining the data as you suggested. However, it gave the same error

Comment: same error :( I tried playing around a lot with the data and ajax code. None worked. Does it have to do with the url redirect format? I tried changing the Redirect Mode in RouteConfig to `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off ` and it gave another error which was `{Message: "Invalid JSON primitive: undefined.",…}

ExceptionType: "System.ArgumentException"
Message: "Invalid JSON primitive: undefined`